# DML ERROR LOG restriction

Tags: oracle, plsql, dml

The following conditions cause the DML ERROR  LOG to fail and roll back without invoking the error logging capability:

1. Violated deferred constraints.
2. Any direct-path INSERT or MERGE operation that raises a unique constraint or index violation.
3. Any update operation UPDATE or MERGE that raises a unique constraint or index violation).
4. You cannot track errors in the error logging table for LONG, LOB, or object type columns. However, the table that is the target of the DML operation can contain these types of columns.

How can I overcome restriction NO.3, I need to manage error log on both INSERT and UPDATE queries but, UPDATE is not supported?

Comment: Sample code demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks alex.k  `UPDATE`s that cause a unique violation are indeed not supported in `LOG ERRORS`, but other `UPDATE` exceptions (and `DELETE`s log ok.  Are you looking specifically at updates that trigger 
 unique violations?  
If so, are you free to change the update statements?  Are you free to change the target `TABLE`s or add any new structures?

Comment: Basically,  I need to record an UPDATE error that caused by unique constraint or index violation into the $err table (the same table that is created as part of the DML LOG procedure). I what to manage one $err table and that the update process will continue on error to update the next row.